# Passing a List to an sql-component query

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I'm having trouble to pass a list of string I'm getting back from my bean to my sql-component query to make a call to the database.

```
<bean ref="fo" method="transformTo(${body})" />
```

So in this upper line of code I'm taking data from the body that is an xml and transform it to json.

```
<bean ref="fot" method="getOTs(${body})" />
```

Then I'm extracting the part I want from the json and return a list of string (method signature) :

```
public List<String> getOTs(String jsonOTs)
```

Now the part that isn't working (I'm getting that one parameter is expected but there are a couple each time)

```
<to uri="sql:insert into dbo.table_example (OT) VALUES :#body;"/>
```

My goal is quite simple, retrieving a list of string from my bean (working) and making and an insert into query. I have only one parameter but multiple values. Example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
(value_list_1),
(value_list_2),
...
(value_list_n);
```

[Example taken from here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bulk insert

For a bulk insert, you need to set the query parameter [`batch`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/sql-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_batch) to `true`, this way, Camel will understand that you want to insert several rows in one batch.

Here is the corresponding `to` endpoint in your case:

```
<to uri="sql:insert into dbo.table_example (OT) VALUES (#)?batch=true"/>
```

### Miscellaneous remarks

Actually, for all the use cases that you listed above, you have no need to explicitly refer to the body.

Indeed, in the case of a bean, you could only specify the method to invoke, Camel is able to inject the body as a parameter of your method and automatically converts it into the expected type which is `String` in your case.

Refers to https://camel.apache.org/manual/bean-binding.html#_parameter_binding for more details.

Regarding the SQL producer, **assuming that you did not change the default configuration**, the proper way is to rather use the placeholder that is `#` by default, Camel will automatically use the content of the body as parameters of the underlying `PreparedStatement`.

So you should retry with:

```
<to uri="sql:insert into dbo.table_example (OT) VALUES (#)"/>
```

If you really want to explicitly refer to the body in your query, you can rather use `:#${body}` as next:

```
<to uri="sql:insert into dbo.table_example (OT) VALUES (:#${body})"/>
```

### Misuse of named parameter

If you only use `#body` as you did, Camel interprets it as a named parameter so it will try to get the value from the body if it is a map by getting the value of the key `body` otherwise it will try to get the value of the header `body` but in your case, there are no such values, therefore, you end up with an error of type

```
Cannot find key [body] in message body or headers to use when setting named
parameter in query [insert into developers (name) values :?body;] on the exchange
```

Comment: Hello, thank your for your answers. In both cases I'm getting an error back :

- Number of parameters mismatch. Expected: 1, was: 2 (I have 2 items in my list of string in this case)

- Conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported

Thank you for your answers

Comment: My body contains the result of the bean with ref "fot" in my example. This means it gets a List of strings. It is not a fixed size I am returning, I'm querying a database and in this example, I have been given two Strings for my List.